# My exec program isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program, that in it you can enter a code in the entry, and the program will execute the code.

When you press Enter, the program will create another entry beneath the previous one.

When you press the button "Execute Program", all the code that you written will be executed.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
     Frame.__init__(self, master)
     self.grid()

     self.entry1=Entry(self)
     self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

     self.bttn1=Button(self, text="Execute code", command=self.execute_code)
     self.bttn1.grid(row=1, column=9, sticky=W)

     self.rows=0

     self.entry1.bind("<Return>", self.down)



  def execute_code(self):
      self.code=self.entry1.get()

      try:
         exec(self.code)
      except:
         print("There is something wrong with this code!")

 def down(self,event):
      self.rows+=1

      entry=Entry(self)
      entry.grid(row=self.rows, column=0, sticky=W)
      self.code=self.code+"\n"+entry.get()
      entry.bind("<Return>", self.down)


root=Tk()
root.title("Executing code")
root.geometry("500x500")
app=Application(root)
```

The problem is, when I press the button, it executes only the first entry.

Can someone tell me whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Instead of adding more and more one-line-entry fields, how about using a single multi-line text field?

Comment: It does execute for say print(3), what are you trying to do?

Comment: And it crashes when you hit Enter.

Comment: It does not crash, but it raises an exception if you hit enter before pressing the button, because `self.code` is not yet defined then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle "multi-line" entries does not work. On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> you create a new `Entry` widget and immediately append its content to `self.code`. However, at that point the content is `''`, and you do not keep a reference to that new `Entry`, either, so there is no way to get the content later, after the user had a chance to enter some text.

You *could* store the different `Entry` instances in a list, but instead I suggest you just use a single multi-line [`Text`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) widget:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.entry1 = Text(self)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text="Execute code", command=self.execute_code)
        self.bttn1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def execute_code(self):
        code = self.entry1.get("0.0", "end")
        try:
            exec(code)
        except:
            print("There is something wrong with this code!")
```